# php json_decode() giving null

Tags: php, json

I have a json string like below

```
{"cv_url":"http://localhost/kaj/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Mir-Ruhul-Amin.doc","cv_path":"C:\wamp\www\kaj/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Mir-Ruhul-Amin.doc"}
```

while trying to decode by php json_decode() it giving me null value.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: how do you get this json ? you encodeing it your self or get it via api for example ?

Comment: I get it by json_encode() function

Comment: how do you encode your array ?

Comment: checkout this: https://3v4l.org/mnP6o seems that there are no problem in both encoding and decoding

Answer (score 2):

That is because your JSON in invalid.
You need to escape it like so:

```
{
    "cv_url": "http://localhost/kaj/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Mir-Ruhul-Amin.doc",
    "cv_path": "C:\\wamp\\www\\kaj/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Mir-Ruhul-Amin.doc"
}
```

So your variable should actually be:

```
'{"cv_url": "http://localhost/kaj/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Mir-Ruhul-Amin.doc","cv_path": "C:\\wamp\\www\\kaj/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Mir-Ruhul-Amin.doc"}'
```

for PHP to decode it.

To escape JSON you can simply encode the array in php first or if that does not suit you you can use the following function:

```
/**
 * @param $value
 * @return mixed
 */
function escapeJsonString($value) {
    $escapers = array("\\", "/", "\"", "\n", "\r", "\t", "\x08", "\x0c");
    $replacements = array("\\\\", "\\/", "\\\"", "\\n", "\\r", "\\t", "\\f", "\\b");
    $result = str_replace($escapers, $replacements, $value);
    return $result;
}
```

TIP:

You can always test the validity of your json on online tools like:

http://jsonlint.com

and

http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: and how he could escape it ? put a full solution